# Numbers are lower than words on html page

Tags: css, fonts

In all strings on web page numbers are slightly lower than other words. It's annoying, especially if string is underlined. I think, that this may be because of some problems with css (without css files problem disappear) but I can't figure out, where to search for these problems. Change of font doesn't help. Can you help me with suggestions?

EDIT: I use CrystalX code: http://www.oswd.org/design/preview/id/3465/
Just change "Crystal" in logo to, say, "555 Crystal"

EDIT 2: fragments from css file:

```
* {min-height:1px;}
body {border:0; margin:0; padding:0; background:#F2F5FE url("../design/bg.gif") 0 0 repeat-x; font:70%/160% "verdana",sans-serif; color:#192666; _text-align:center;}

p {border:0; margin:15px 0; padding:0;}

div {display:block; border:0; margin:0; padding:0;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {border:0; margin:15px 0 10px 0; padding:0; font-weight:bold;}
h1 {font-size:260%; line-height:100%; font-family:"georgia",serif; font-weight:normal;}
#main {width:770px; margin:60px auto 0 auto; _text-align:left;}

/* Header */
#header {position:relative; width:770px; height:100px; margin:0; padding:0; background:#233C9B url("../design/header.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat; color:#FFF;}
    /* Header - logo */
    #header #logo {position:absolute; top:35px; left:35px; margin:0;}
    #header #logo a {color:#FFF;}
    #header #logo a:hover {color:#B5C4E3; text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: Could you post some of your markup and styling?

Comment: I find the best strategy in this case is to reduce things as much as possible. Make a copy of your HTML and CSS files, then delete big chunks of your CSS until the problem goes away. Add the last chunk back, and delete smaller chunks until you know what specific rule is your problem. Then you'll either have your answer, or your question here will be specific enough that we can help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is font-face issue. The font "georgia" is the culprit. Try changing your `h1` to other fonts, well let's say "Verdana" and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to change Verdana to other font and overlooked Georgia

Comment: If I may clarify - this isn't actually a "problem" with the typeface as such. Georgia uses old-style numerical figures that are less distracting when used in long pieces of text. True, they may not work as well in headings - but the accepted answer seems a little incomplete without this information.